# Rails inner joins omits a column in result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this

```
[3] pry(main)> Issue
=> Issue(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, 
         release_date: string)
```

And another that looks like this

```
[7] pry(main)> Tip
 => Tip(id: integer, author: string, code: string, summary: string, 
        description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, 
         issue_id: integer)
```

The problem is that when I run this sql query a column is omitted, wondering why that might be the case.

```
 Tip.joins("INNER JOIN issues on issue_id = issues.id").select("tips.summary, 
          issues.*, issues.id")
 Tip Load (0.3ms)  SELECT tips.summary, issues.*, issues.id FROM "tips" 
       INNER JOIN issues on issue_id = issues.id
 => [#<Tip id: 1, summary: "List the leafs in the tree of changes", 
    created_at: "2014-02-02 04:15:19", updated_at: "2014-02-02 04:15:19">]
```

Notice the generated sql query from above. Wondering why the `release_date` column is missing from the result.

Actually, I even tried this and that did not work as well.

```
Tip.joins("INNER JOIN issues on issue_id = issues.id").select("tips.summary,  
  issues.release_date, issues.id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just the `release_date` that's hidden in the result.  Any fields that you `select` that are not member of `Tip` class would be hidden.

If your query succeeded which it looks like it did, you can access `release_date` as:

```
result = Tip.joins("INNER JOIN issues on issue_id = issues.id").select("tips.summary,  
  issues.release_date, issues.id").first
puts result['release_date']
```